# Angular redirect happens always?

Tags: angular

I have this:

```js
    this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                    },
                    error => {
                        this.alertService.error(error);
                        this.loading = false;
                    });
```

here is the login method:

```js
     login(username, password) {
            return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:8000/api/Authinticate`, { username, password })
                .pipe(map(user => {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    console.log(user);
                    //this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                    return user;
                }));
        }
```

even I provide wrong credentials

```
 this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
```

the redirect happens

Comment: The `error` handler is going to be invoked only on communication errors. If the server is returning a 200 response, maybe with a body containing an error message, you are not checking _in any way_ the `data` response of the server. Try to debug it (do you know how to use `debugger` statements?) and check what `data` actually contains.

Comment: I for got to retun 400  in bad req